# Events and callbacks firing incorrectly in pushwoosh push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, cordova

I'm using the plugin's `registerDevice` and `unregisterDevice` methods and looking at my app's control panel in pushwoosh. My app's preference defaults to accepting push notifications, so I register, that works and my subscriber count increments in pushwoosh control panel. It also fires a `push-notification` event where the event has the `notification` property as the guide shows, but it's set to `null`. This is confusing as I have not yet sent any push notifications from the control panel.

I then set my push preference to `false` and unregister the the device. It works because my subscriber count decrements in the control panel, but the `fail` callback is the one that fires, and the only argument it gets is the same push token string that the register `success` callback got. If I unregister again after that, still only the `fail` callback fires but this time the only argument is the empty string.

Am I doing something wrong with handling responses from the plugin?

The code I'm testing with:

```
(function() {
    $document.on('push-notification', function(evt) {
        var n = evt.originalEvent.notification;
        console.log(n);
    });

    var pushPrefApply = function() {
        app.pushPref(function(pushPref) {
            console.log('pushPref', pushPref);
            if (!pushPref) {
                window.plugins.pushNotification.unregisterDevice(
                    function() {
                        console.log('unreg ok', arguments);
                    },
                    function() {
                        console.log('unreg fail', arguments);
                    }
                );
                return;
            }
            window.plugins.pushNotification.registerDevice(
                {
                    projectid: '123456789012',
                    appid : 'F0000-BAAAA'
                },
                function(pushToken) {
                    console.log('reg ok', arguments);
                },
                function(status) {
                    console.log('reg fail', arguments);
                }
            );
        });
    };

    //code for changing/initiating push preference goes here
})();
```

`$document` is not a typo, it's defined already. `app.pushPref` is the preference setting/fetching function. `window.plugins.pushNotification.onDeviceReady` has been done elsewhere on `deviceready`.

I'm hoping the pushwoosh devs will shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed and SDK has been updated on Github:
https://github.com/shaders/push-notifications-sdk
and
https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-cordova-push-notifications

Also Android Phonegap sample now includes unregister function:
https://github.com/shaders/push-notifications-sdk/tree/master/SDK%20Sample%20Projects/Android-Phonegap